# How to prevent or change the R base default editor from copying text with colored whitespace?

Tags: r, editor

In R's default editor, when I copy and paste code into it, it consistently retains the source formatting. For example, if I were to copy a code snippet (which is on a gray background) from this site,

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-basics-quick-and-easy

```
7 + 4 # => 11
7 - 4 # => 3
7 / 2 # => 3.5
7 * 2 # => 14
```

My default R editor shows gray spaces in between. Furthermore, I am unable to modify it by going to "Show Colors". How can I fix or remedy this issue? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'paste as plain text' option with the shortcut option+command+v (macos: R 3.6.1 GUI 1.70 El Capitan build (7684)); does your GUI have a similar option & shortcut under the `Edit` tab?